# I have problem with the generated file .java form web3j

Tags: android-studio, blockchain, solidity, web3js

I have project in the mobile application and blockchain, i create all the smart contract that i well use in the project uinf solidity here is the first one that i will use :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract UserRegistrationContract {
    // Enumération pour représenter le profil de l'utilisateur
    enum UserProfile { Requester, Worker }

    // Structure pour représenter un utilisateur
    struct User {
        UserProfile profile; // Profil de l'utilisateur (Requester ou Worker)
        uint256 points; // Point de l'utilisateur
    }

    // Mapping pour associer une adresse Ethereum à un utilisateur
    mapping(address => User) public users;

    // Ensembles pour stocker les adresses des Requesters et Workers
    address[] public requesterPool;
    address[] public workerPool;

    // Événements pour signaler l'enregistrement d'un utilisateur
    event UserRegistered(address indexed user, UserProfile profile, uint256 points);
    // Événements pour signaler l'ajout d'un utilisateur au pool
    event RequesterAdded(address indexed requester); //ajput de requester
    event WorkerAdded(address indexed worker); //ajout de worker

    // Fonction d'enregistrement d'un nouvel utilisateur
    function addUser(UserProfile profile, uint256 points) public returns (bool) {

        // Vérifiez si l'adresse n'est pas déjà dans l'ensemble des workers et requester
        require(profile != UserProfile.Worker || !isAddressInArray(msg.sender, workerPool), "Worker already registered");
        require(profile != UserProfile.Requester || !isAddressInArray(msg.sender, requesterPool), "Requester already registered");

        // Initialiser l'utilisateur avec ses données
        users[msg.sender] = User({
            profile: profile,
            points: points
        });

        // Émettre un événement pour signaler l'enregistrement de l'utilisateur
        emit UserRegistered(msg.sender, profile, points);

        // Ajouter l'adresse de l'utilisateur au pool approprié
        if (profile == UserProfile.Requester) { // si le profil est requester
            requesterPool.push(msg.sender);
            emit RequesterAdded(msg.sender);
        } else if (profile == UserProfile.Worker) { //si le profil est worker
            workerPool.push(msg.sender);
            emit WorkerAdded(msg.sender);
        }

        // Retourner vrai pour indiquer un enregistrement réussi
        return true;
    }

    // Fonction pour vérifier si une adresse existe dans un ensemble
    function isAddressInArray(address _address, address[] storage _array) internal view returns (bool) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
            if (_array[i] == _address) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Fonctions pour récupérer les adresses des Requesters et Workers
    function getRequesters() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return requesterPool;
    }
    function getWorkers() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return workerPool;
    }

    //Fonction pour verifier si l'address donnée est selle de requester
    function isRequesterRegistered(address requesterAddress) public view returns (bool) {
    return users[requesterAddress].profile == UserProfile.Requester;
    }

    //Fonction pour recuperer les points d'un utilisateur 
    function getPoints(address userAddress) public view returns (uint256) {
    return users[userAddress].points;}

    //Fonction pour ajouter des points au points d un utilisateur
    function addPoints(address userAddress, uint256 pointsToAdd) public {
    users[userAddress].points += pointsToAdd;
    }

    //Fonction pour retirer des poitns au points d un utilisateur
    function subtructPoints(address userAddress, uint256 pointsTosubtract) public {
    users[userAddress].points -= pointsTosubtract;
    }

}
```

And here is the generated file

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class UserRegistrationContract extends Contract {
    public static final String BINARY = "3";

    public static final String FUNC_ADDPOINTS = "addPoints";

    public static final String FUNC_ADDUSER = "addUser";

    public static final String FUNC_GETPOINTS = "getPoints";

    public static final String FUNC_GETREQUESTERS = "getRequesters";

    public static final String FUNC_GETWORKERS = "getWorkers";

    public static final String FUNC_ISREQUESTERREGISTERED = "isRequesterRegistered";

    public static final String FUNC_REQUESTERPOOL = "requesterPool";

    public static final String FUNC_SUBTRUCTPOINTS = "subtructPoints";

    public static final String FUNC_USERS = "users";

    public static final String FUNC_WORKERPOOL = "workerPool";

    public static final Event REQUESTERADDED_EVENT = new Event("RequesterAdded", 
            Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}));
    ;

    public static final Event USERREGISTERED_EVENT = new Event("UserRegistered", 
            Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}, new TypeReference<Uint8>() {}, new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
    ;

    public static final Event WORKERADDED_EVENT = new Event("WorkerAdded", 
            Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}));
    ;

    @Deprecated
    protected UserRegistrationContract(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    protected UserRegistrationContract(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider);
    }

    @Deprecated
    protected UserRegistrationContract(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    protected UserRegistrationContract(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider);
    }

    public static List<RequesterAddedEventResponse> getRequesterAddedEvents(TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt) {
        List<Contract.EventValuesWithLog> valueList = staticExtractEventParametersWithLog(REQUESTERADDED_EVENT, transactionReceipt);
        ArrayList<RequesterAddedEventResponse> responses = new ArrayList<RequesterAddedEventResponse>(valueList.size());
        for (Contract.EventValuesWithLog eventValues : valueList) {
            RequesterAddedEventResponse typedResponse = new RequesterAddedEventResponse();
            typedResponse.log = eventValues.getLog();
            typedResponse.requester = (String) eventValues.getIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
            responses.add(typedResponse);
        }
        return responses;
    }

    public static RequesterAddedEventResponse getRequesterAddedEventFromLog(Log log) {
        Contract.EventValuesWithLog eventValues = staticExtractEventParametersWithLog(REQUESTERADDED_EVENT, log);
        RequesterAddedEventResponse typedResponse = new RequesterAddedEventResponse();
        typedResponse.log = log;
        typedResponse.requester = (String) eventValues.getIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
        return typedResponse;
    }

    public Flowable<RequesterAddedEventResponse> requesterAddedEventFlowable(EthFilter filter) {
        return web3j.ethLogFlowable(filter).map(log -> getRequesterAddedEventFromLog(log));
    }

    public Flowable<RequesterAddedEventResponse> requesterAddedEventFlowable(DefaultBlockParameter startBlock, DefaultBlockParameter endBlock) {
        EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(startBlock, endBlock, getContractAddress());
        filter.addSingleTopic(EventEncoder.encode(REQUESTERADDED_EVENT));
        return requesterAddedEventFlowable(filter);
    }

    public static List<UserRegisteredEventResponse> getUserRegisteredEvents(TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt) {
        List<Contract.EventValuesWithLog> valueList = staticExtractEventParametersWithLog(USERREGISTERED_EVENT, transactionReceipt);
        ArrayList<UserRegisteredEventResponse> responses = new ArrayList<UserRegisteredEventResponse>(valueList.size());
        for (Contract.EventValuesWithLog eventValues : valueList) {
            UserRegisteredEventResponse typedResponse = new UserRegisteredEventResponse();
            typedResponse.log = eventValues.getLog();
            typedResponse.user = (String) eventValues.getIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
            typedResponse.profile = (BigInteger) eventValues.getNonIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
            typedResponse.points = (BigInteger) eventValues.getNonIndexedValues().get(1).getValue();
            responses.add(typedResponse);
        }
        return responses;
    }

    public static UserRegisteredEventResponse getUserRegisteredEventFromLog(Log log) {
        Contract.EventValuesWithLog eventValues = staticExtractEventParametersWithLog(USERREGISTERED_EVENT, log);
        UserRegisteredEventResponse typedResponse = new UserRegisteredEventResponse();
        typedResponse.log = log;
        typedResponse.user = (String) eventValues.getIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
        typedResponse.profile = (BigInteger) eventValues.getNonIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
        typedResponse.points = (BigInteger) eventValues.getNonIndexedValues().get(1).getValue();
        return typedResponse;
    }

    public Flowable<UserRegisteredEventResponse> userRegisteredEventFlowable(EthFilter filter) {
        return web3j.ethLogFlowable(filter).map(log -> getUserRegisteredEventFromLog(log));
    }

    public Flowable<UserRegisteredEventResponse> userRegisteredEventFlowable(DefaultBlockParameter startBlock, DefaultBlockParameter endBlock) {
        EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(startBlock, endBlock, getContractAddress());
        filter.addSingleTopic(EventEncoder.encode(USERREGISTERED_EVENT));
        return userRegisteredEventFlowable(filter);
    }

    public static List<WorkerAddedEventResponse> getWorkerAddedEvents(TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt) {
        List<Contract.EventValuesWithLog> valueList = staticExtractEventParametersWithLog(WORKERADDED_EVENT, transactionReceipt);
        ArrayList<WorkerAddedEventResponse> responses = new ArrayList<WorkerAddedEventResponse>(valueList.size());
        for (Contract.EventValuesWithLog eventValues : valueList) {
            WorkerAddedEventResponse typedResponse = new WorkerAddedEventResponse();
            typedResponse.log = eventValues.getLog();
            typedResponse.worker = (String) eventValues.getIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
            responses.add(typedResponse);
        }
        return responses;
    }

    public static WorkerAddedEventResponse getWorkerAddedEventFromLog(Log log) {
        Contract.EventValuesWithLog eventValues = staticExtractEventParametersWithLog(WORKERADDED_EVENT, log);
        WorkerAddedEventResponse typedResponse = new WorkerAddedEventResponse();
        typedResponse.log = log;
        typedResponse.worker = (String) eventValues.getIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
        return typedResponse;
    }

    public Flowable<WorkerAddedEventResponse> workerAddedEventFlowable(EthFilter filter) {
        return web3j.ethLogFlowable(filter).map(log -> getWorkerAddedEventFromLog(log));
    }

    public Flowable<WorkerAddedEventResponse> workerAddedEventFlowable(DefaultBlockParameter startBlock, DefaultBlockParameter endBlock) {
        EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(startBlock, endBlock, getContractAddress());
        filter.addSingleTopic(EventEncoder.encode(WORKERADDED_EVENT));
        return workerAddedEventFlowable(filter);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<TransactionReceipt> addPoints(String userAddress, BigInteger pointsToAdd) {
        final Function function = new Function(
                FUNC_ADDPOINTS, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(160, userAddress), 
                new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(pointsToAdd)), 
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<TransactionReceipt> addUser(BigInteger profile, BigInteger points) {
        final Function function = new Function(
                FUNC_ADDUSER, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint8(profile), 
                new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(points)), 
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<BigInteger> getPoints(String userAddress) {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_GETPOINTS, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(160, userAddress)), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
        return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, BigInteger.class);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<List> getRequesters() {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_GETREQUESTERS, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<DynamicArray<Address>>() {}));
        return new RemoteFunctionCall<List>(function,
                new Callable<List>() {
                    @Override
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public List call() throws Exception {
                        List<Type> result = (List<Type>) executeCallSingleValueReturn(function, List.class);
                        return convertToNative(result);
                    }
                });
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<List> getWorkers() {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_GETWORKERS, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<DynamicArray<Address>>() {}));
        return new RemoteFunctionCall<List>(function,
                new Callable<List>() {
                    @Override
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public List call() throws Exception {
                        List<Type> result = (List<Type>) executeCallSingleValueReturn(function, List.class);
                        return convertToNative(result);
                    }
                });
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<Boolean> isRequesterRegistered(String requesterAddress) {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_ISREQUESTERREGISTERED, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(160, requesterAddress)), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Bool>() {}));
        return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, Boolean.class);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<String> requesterPool(BigInteger param0) {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_REQUESTERPOOL, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(param0)), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>() {}));
        return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, String.class);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<TransactionReceipt> subtructPoints(String userAddress, BigInteger pointsTosubtract) {
        final Function function = new Function(
                FUNC_SUBTRUCTPOINTS, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(160, userAddress), 
                new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(pointsTosubtract)), 
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<Tuple2<BigInteger, BigInteger>> users(String param0) {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_USERS, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(160, param0)), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint8>() {}, new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
        return new RemoteFunctionCall<Tuple2<BigInteger, BigInteger>>(function,
                new Callable<Tuple2<BigInteger, BigInteger>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<BigInteger, BigInteger> call() throws Exception {
                        List<Type> results = executeCallMultipleValueReturn(function);
                        return new Tuple2<BigInteger, BigInteger>(
                                (BigInteger) results.get(0).getValue(), 
                                (BigInteger) results.get(1).getValue());
                    }
                });
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<String> workerPool(BigInteger param0) {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_WORKERPOOL, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(param0)), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>() {}));
        return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, String.class);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static UserRegistrationContract load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new UserRegistrationContract(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static UserRegistrationContract load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new UserRegistrationContract(contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    public static UserRegistrationContract load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return new UserRegistrationContract(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider);
    }

    public static UserRegistrationContract load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return new UserRegistrationContract(contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider);
    }

    public static RemoteCall<UserRegistrationContract> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return deployRemoteCall(UserRegistrationContract.class, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider, BINARY, "");
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static RemoteCall<UserRegistrationContract> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(UserRegistrationContract.class, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }

    public static RemoteCall<UserRegistrationContract> deploy(Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return deployRemoteCall(UserRegistrationContract.class, web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider, BINARY, "");
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static RemoteCall<UserRegistrationContract> deploy(Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(UserRegistrationContract.class, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }

    public static class RequesterAddedEventResponse extends BaseEventResponse {
        public String requester;
    }

    public static class UserRegisteredEventResponse extends BaseEventResponse {
        public String user;

        public BigInteger profile;

        public BigInteger points;
    }

    public static class WorkerAddedEventResponse extends BaseEventResponse {
        public String worker;
    }
}
```

I keep geting this error idk why :

```
'staticExtractEventParametersWithLog(org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Event, org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.Log)' in 'org.web3j.tx.Contract' cannot be applied to '(org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Event, org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.TransactionReceipt)'
```

It's in the  transactionReceipt variable.
[The function where I have problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1rLB.png)

Idk if I need to make changes in the code or what?

Comment: To help others understand your issue and to aid in finding a solution I would recommend you provide a [minimal, workable example (mwe)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue you are facing. It's possible that the process of doing so sheds new light on the problem at hand. Regardless it will aid others in helping you. Please consider this when next posting a question, to aid in solving your future problems as quickly as possible. :)

Comment: I'm having the same error from generated code using the cli

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and as a workaround I've changed the generated code like this:

```java
// Original generated code
    public static List<NewUserEventResponse> getNewUserEvents(TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt) {
        List<Contract.EventValuesWithLog> valueList = staticExtractEventParametersWithLog(NEWUSER_EVENT, transactionReceipt);
        ArrayList<NewUserEventResponse> responses = new ArrayList<NewUserEventResponse>(valueList.size());
        for (Contract.EventValuesWithLog eventValues : valueList) {
            NewUserEventResponse typedResponse = new NewUserEventResponse();
            typedResponse.log = eventValues.getLog();
            typedResponse.user = (String) eventValues.getNonIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
            typedResponse.nickname = (String) eventValues.getNonIndexedValues().get(1).getValue();
            responses.add(typedResponse);
        }
        return responses;
    }
```

The change is to iterate through TransactionReceipt logs:

```java
// Workaround
    public static List<NewUserEventResponse> getNewUserEvents(TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt) {
        ArrayList<NewUserEventResponse> responses = new ArrayList<NewUserEventResponse>();

        for (Log log : transactionReceipt.getLogs()) {
            NewUserEventResponse typedResponse = new NewUserEventResponse();
            Contract.EventValuesWithLog eventValue = staticExtractEventParametersWithLog(NEWUSER_EVENT, log);
            typedResponse.log = eventValue.getLog();
            typedResponse.user = (String) eventValue.getNonIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
            typedResponse.nickname = (String) eventValue.getNonIndexedValues().get(1).getValue();
            responses.add(typedResponse);
        }

        return responses;
    }
```

So, if I'm not mistaken, your code should look like this:

```java
    public static List<WorkerAddedEventResponse> getWorkerAddedEvents(TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt) {
        ArrayList<WorkerAddedEventResponse> responses = new ArrayList<WorkerAddedEventResponse>();
        
        for (Log log : transactionReceipt.getLogs()) {
            Contract.EventValuesWithLog eventValue = staticExtractEventParametersWithLog(WORKERADDED_EVENT, log);

            WorkerAddedEventResponse typedResponse = new WorkerAddedEventResponse();
            typedResponse.log = eventValue.getLog();
            typedResponse.worker = (String) eventValue.getIndexedValues().get(0).getValue();
            responses.add(typedResponse);
        }
        
        return responses;
    }
```